# CurvedArrows in sigjma.js, typescript and npm

Tags: typescript, npm, sigma.js

I would like to draw curved arrows in sigma.js within my typescript npm project. The following occures on browser/client-side:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'process')
    at Sigma.process (bundle.js:5088:42)
    at new Sigma (bundle.js:4656:15)
    at Object.complete (bundle.js:6434:17)
    at l.parseChunk (bundle.js:1964:6719)
    at l._chunkLoaded (bundle.js:1964:8287)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous>
```

I just changed the edge type from "arrow" to "curvedArrow" and didn't worked. Do i need to import any particular curvedArrow.js files into my npm project?

```
graph.addEdge(parent_node, child_node, {
                size: 1,
                color: '#d6d6d6',
                type: "curvedArrow"
            });
```

Current dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/sigmajs": "^1.0.28",
    "commonjs": "^0.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "graphology": "^0.23.2",
    "graphology-components": "^1.5.2",
    "graphology-layout": "^0.5.0",
    "graphology-layout-forceatlas2": "^0.8.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "sigma": "^2.1.3",
    "xhr": "^2.6.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no curved edge in Sigma2 for the moment